# ZipOutputStream on mp3 corrupts files - Creates data files not audio files

Tags: java, android, zip, zipoutputstream

I am using ZipOutputStream in an Android app to package and export mp3 files. The package and export appears to work fine, when the files are extracted, they are not playable. Running `file` command on the output shows the file type as `data`. Prior to zipping the file type is listed as `Audio`. 
Here's the code I'm using  to compress the files:

```
 protected File compressFiles(File outputFile, File... inputFiles) {

    int bufferSize = 1024 * 4; // 4KB
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = null;
    try {
        OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream));
        int count = inputFiles.length;
        File file = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < inputFiles.length; i++) {
            file = inputFiles[i];

            String fileName = file.getName();
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
            entry.setTime(file.lastModified());
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

            zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(entry);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            zipOutputStream.closeEntry();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (zipOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                zipOutputStream.finish();
               // zipOutputStream.flush();
                zipOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return outputFile;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong overload of the `BufferedInputStream.read()` method.

You probably meant to pass in the `byte[] buffer` as a parameter, but instead, you didn't pass in any parameters. As a result you are only writing out zeroes from the `buffer` variable.  In fact, even the `bytesRead` variable has the wrong value, as it returns the actual byte being read instead of the number of bytes.

To fix, simply change this line:

```
while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
```

to this:

```
while ((bytesRead = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
```